# 'document.writeln(something(params))' does nothing

Tags: javascript

I am newbie of JavaScript and studying with textbook. I wrote below code, and alert modal window was displayed correctly, but `document.writeln(triangle(8,5))` does nothing. Why?

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Area of Triangle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Area of Triangle</h1>
    <pre>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            <!--

            var triangle;

            triangle = function(base, height) {
              return base * height / 2;
            };

            alert(triangle(8, 5));

            documnt.writeln(triangle(8, 5));

            -->
        </script>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: The typo?  documnt -> document

Comment: You had a typo. It should be `document`, not "documnt".

Comment: You have a typo in the code, it's missing an "e". Does it work if you remove the alert before the write, or change their positions? Also, check your error console

Comment: I am sorry that this question is entirely my careless typing miss. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in their code, which is unlikely to help future viewers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misspelled `document` as `documnt`. Try:

```
document.writeln(triangle(8, 5));
```